# Is it possible to use the Laplace Transform to calculate eigenvalues?

Tags: fourier-analysis, convex-optimization, eigenvalues, laplace-transform

#### The relationship of Eigenvalues with Gradient Descent

Let $A$ be a symmetric (and thus diagonalizable) matrix, with diagonalization

$$A=VDV^T.$$

Let us define the quadratic function

$$f(x) = x^T A x.$$

Then gradient descent on $f$ for starting point $x_0$ with learning rate $h$ can be written as

$$x_n = x_{n-1} -h\nabla f(x_{n-1}) = (I-hA)x_{n-1}.$$

Or to highlight the eigenvalues

$$V^T x_n = (I-hD)V^Tx_{n-1}.$$

Taking an eigenvector $v_i$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ out of $V$ this implies

$$x^{(i)}_n := \langle v_i, x_n\rangle =(1-h\lambda_i)x_{n-1}^{(i)} = (1-h\lambda_i)^nx_0^{(i)}.$$

#### Relation to the Laplace Transform

Now this means that for the discrete measure

$$\mu(x) = \sum_{i=1}^d x_0^{(i)}1_{\{x=-\log(1-h\lambda_i)\}}$$

we get some evaluations of the Laplace Transform of $\mu$

$$
\|x_n\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^d (x_0^{(i)})^2(1-h\lambda_i)^{2n}
=\int_{[0,\infty)} \exp(-2n x)d\mu(x) = \mathcal{L}\{\mu\}(2n)
$$

Similarly we get

$$
f(x_n)=(x_0^{(i)})^2(1-h\lambda_i)^{2n+1} = \mathcal{L}\{\mu\}(2n+1)
$$

#### Inverting the Laplace Transform somehow?

If we could invert our Laplace transform we would of course immediately get the eigenvalues as the non-zero "frequencies" in our discrete measure $\mu$. And since the discrete FFT blurs frequencies over adjacent ones if you do not hit them exactly I would expect this to at least provide a useful insight into the upper and lower bound (i.e. condition number) with very little precision. Since the condition number can be used for calculating optimal learning rates, this would be very helpful in accelerating gradient descent (although in that case we would have to do with function evaluations only, since we generally do not know where the minimum is in contrast to this centred example where it is always in 0).

Now the issue is of course that we do not get arbitrary evaluations of our Laplace transform and the Inverse Laplace Transform demands evaluations on the complex axis.

But maybe someone else has an idea how to salvage this situation. Maybe there is a less efficient algorithm than the Z-Transform which can do with those evaluations only, maybe we can reformulate gradient descent a bit to get a representation which allows complex evaluations.

I thought this insight was neat and Laplace Transform would be considerably faster than current eigenvalue calculation algorithms if this could be resolved - so I wanted to throw this out here.

Answer (score 2):

A very unsatisfying answer is matrix exponentiation (which is very expensive itself):

$$x_n=\exp(ihA)x_{n-1}$$

results in

$$
x_n^{(j)} = \exp(ih\lambda_jn) x_0^{(j)}
$$

and thus

$$
\|x_n\|^2 = \sum_{j=1}^d (x_0^{(j)})^2 \exp(i2hn\lambda_i)
$$

This process seems to be basically the idea of [Quantum Phase Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_phase_estimation_algorithm).

Comment: I wonder if the approximation $(1-hiA)\approx\exp(-hiA)$ is valid...

Comment: $I+A\approx \exp(A)$ appears to give a very good approximation in high dimensions when $I+A$ is the operator of optimization method like gradient descent, wondering if imaginary part makes this approximation more brittle

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov hey, it is been some time and I am not really in-topic anymore. But given the usual derivation of optimal step sizes (e.g. https://distill.pub/2017/momentum/ ) I would think that A is not close to zero. I mean the entire point is trying to achieve $(1-h \lambda_d) = (1- h \lambda_1)$ which requies $h \lambda_d$ to be larger than 1 for the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_d$. I mean you could purposefully select smaller step-sizes, but...

Comment: Indeed, you want this to work for actual step sizes used in practice. This approximation works for large step sizes when eigenvalues decay and dimensionality is large. Here's [example](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-expt-approximation.nb) of using it for minimizing x^2+1/2 y^2+.... with step size 1

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov But if $h\lambda_d$ is greater than 1, then $(1-h\lambda_d)\not\approx \exp(1-h\lambda_d)$. I am also not sure why decaying eigenvalues would be plausible. I mean you would expect the hessian to be approximately constant close to the minimum due to the second taylor approximation.

Comment: It's smaller than one for majority of eigenvalues in typical high dimensional setting because of eigenvalue decay. For neural networks they've been observed to decay as power law, with p around 1

Comment: Decaying eigenvalues happens for random matrices. it's open question why NN Hessian eigs decay as power law , some references https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-velikanov-berthier-example.nb

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov if the eigenvalues were to decay, would it not make sense to increase the learning rate? Due to the optimality arguments in distill.pub/2017/momentum? I am completely unfamiliar with this concept of eigenvalue decay. I will try to read up on it

Comment: You are thinking of decay in time rather than in decay in coefficients. Consider $J=x_1^2+\frac{1}{2}x_2^2+\frac{1}{3}x_3^2+\ldots+\frac{1}{d}x_d^2$. Largest stable learning rate is determined by coefficient in front of $x_1$, so it's independent of the rate of decay of coefficients. Take step-size=1. You [can see](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/mathoverflow-rank1-recurrence-simple.nb) that for $d=17$, your GD state transition matrix for time $t$ is $(1-H)^t \approx \exp(-Ht)  \text{ where } H_{ii}=\frac{1}{i}$, $1\le i \le d$

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov hm, so you are saying the approximation holds for most eigenspaces (which are not the largest eigenvalue)?

Comment: B Right...ie, exp approximation is bad for a few dimensions, but as we increase $d$, the relative contribution of those dimensions to overall loss goes down. For $p=1$ decay, I expect $\exp$ approximation to be exact in the limit of $d\to \infty$

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Wouldn't the largest eigenvalue also have an outsized influence on the value of $Ht$ though? Hm, I mean you can do this entrywise I guess since you can move basis changes out of $\exp$....

Comment: For $x_1^2 +\ldots + \frac{1}{d}x_d^2$, influence of largest eigenvalue is 1, but sum of all eigenvalues is $\log d$, so the relative influence of largest eigenvalue is $\frac{1}{\log d}$, goes to 0 with $d$

Comment: Looking at Taylor expansion of $(1-H)^t$ and $\exp(-Ht)$ it appears that sufficient condition for equivalence in $d\to \infty$ limit is that $\operatorname{Tr}H$ diverges, but $\operatorname{Tr}H^2$ converges

Answer (score 1):

There's indeed a connection. First you can get rid of $x_0$ as follows -- starting with random $x_0$ initialized on a sphere, expected squared error $f(t)$ at time $t$ [can be shown](https://machine-learning-etc.ghost.io/why-condition-number-doesnt-matter/) to be

$$f(t)=\operatorname{Tr}((I-A)^{2t})$$

In high dimensions, this is not only an average value, but also a "typical value", almost all trajectories will concentrate around this average.

Now if we use $\exp(-t)\approx (I-A)^t$ approximation we can write

$$f(t)=E[e^{-2 \lambda t}]$$

Where expectation is taken over empirical eigenvalue density of $A$ eigenvalues.

This is the moment generating function, so we can invert it symbolically using inverse Laplace transform. Given eigenvalue density, we [can get](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4185467/rate-of-eigenvalue-decay-for-erd%c5%91s-r%c3%a9nyi-random-graph/4187243#comment8681583_4187243) formula for $k$th eigenvalue from the CDF of this density.

A complete example is worked out [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2362355) for the harder case when average loss rather than average error is observed.

The issue with this approach is that it requires explicit symbolic form of $f(t)$, it's not clear how to adapt it to the case when $f(t)$ is known at a number of discrete intervals.